# CSS : overflow : auto will not work under FireFox 3.6.2

Tags: css, firefox

This is a CSS related question, I got one good answer from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549665/jquery-to-add-vertical-scroll-bar-for-a-fixed-height-div-container), which suggested the use of some CSS code like overflow:auto together with a fixed height container.

And here is my actual implementation : [on uni server](http://www-student.it.uts.edu.au/~cmao/ip/)

If by any chance you cannot access that server, try [this](http://chenximao.net/protected/ip/)

Please follow the instructions on screen and buy more than 4 kinds of tickets.

If you are using IE8, Opera, Safari, Chrome, you would notice that the lower right corner of the page now has a vertical scroll bar, which scrolls the content inside it and prevent it from overflowing. That's what I want to have in this section.

Now the problem is, this would not do in FireFox 3.6.2. Am I doing something not compliant to the CSS standard or FireFox has its own way of overflow control?

You can inspect the elements on screen, and all controlling functions are done in one javascript using jQuery. All CSS code is kept in a separated file as well.

According to the professor, FireFox would be the target browser, although the version was set to 2.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to set a height / overflow to the <tbody> tag, not just the table (or maybe not the table at all, didn't test that).

So...

```
tbody { height: 130px; overflow: auto; }
```

And I specifically tested with "height", it seemed "max-height" didn't work as intended. Very odd behavior, indeed.

Comment: @RussellUresti : you are sooooooo right! OMG, this stuck me for a couple of days...

Comment: @Michael: I don't know which table you mean (#carttable?), but this doesn't solve the problem for me at all, in FF 3.6.3 I still see the buttons diving under those icons

Comment: @Marcel I'm on 3.6.3 as well, and he's talking about the table with the id of "carttable". If you use firebug to add the height and overflow to the tbody tag inside that table, it will scroll.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel : I am using FireFox 3.6.2 and this is the screenshot:
http://i43.tinypic.com/juwqjq.png and that is all right. I will check for more but at least I can see where to try fixing this issue

Comment: @Michael: Ah, now I understand and of course this is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overflow: scroll?